# Div inside a container to have width greater then container width

Tags: html, css

We want a top bar on our page which is as wide as the browser's width. The problem is, it is inside a container div. If you pull it out of the container we can expand the div to the body width, but when it is inside the container it can only expand to the width of container.

Is there a solution through which we can expand the topbar past the container div.

```
<div id="container">
     <div id="topBar">
         <p>The Paragraph</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is your code? Depending on how it is structured and what overflows are given it might be possible

Comment: @SvenBieder : i have posted the code, there are no overflows given. Only simple height and widths are used.

Comment: You could give `#topBar` absolute positioning which would remove it from the flow which allows you to give it 100% width, while `#container` stays at whatever other width you need.

Comment: When you have nothing special given, then this will work: http://jsfiddle.net/xexJK/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can position the `#topBar` absolute without making it relative to its' immediate parent

```css
html, body {
    height: 2000px;
}

#container {
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 200px;
    background: beige;
}

#topBar {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    background: #ccc;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/g2DrW/)

Comment: That's what I was thinking, though he would probably want to put some margin-top on #container to make sure it doesn't fall under #topBar, right? Or will `margin: auto;` try to center it both vertically as well as horizontally?

Comment: @zoltan: Will the same solution work if there the paragraph is two div down... I mean there is a also a header div in which the topbar is placed?

Comment: @mori nope - `margin: auto` wont center it vertically.. you have to use one of `padding-top` or `margin-top` to move the content of the container down..

Comment: @ZoltanToth: I tried to mimic it but could not do it, it works great on jsFiddle but when i post it in my document, as soon as i set the position to absolute, the topBar div vanishes. Sorry i could not refer to a page as i am developing locally and the css and HTML are huge to post here.

Comment: check if your topBar has any height (if it's empty it collapses), if it has any type of negative margins that can hide it etc.

Comment: @ZoltanToth: Thanks a lot the problem was with width, it was having zero width. Also the header div was having a position relative as soon as i changed it to static, the topBar div popped out of both header and container..

Answer (score 1):

The other possibility is to remove it from the document flow with position:absolute. However, you need to know your height of the topBar, and will have to compensate by forcing a top margin on the rest of your content to keep it below your topBar.

For example, you could do:

```
#topBar {
    position:absolute; /* fixed might also work, here */
    top:0; left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
}
```

but you'd also have to have:

```
#container {
    margin-top:50px; /* or more */
}
```

This will break, however, if you need to make #container `position:absolute` or `position:relative`.